# "Toned" and "Endless" Pins

Tags: vocabulary, slang, colloquial-language

In [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pin) listed at number 14 is this definition of **pin**: *Informal* **a human leg**.

[image: Kylie Minogue]

"Legs that go on forever: Kylie showed off her enviable **pins** in the dress, which she teamed with black heels"

Nowadays online newspapers keep referring to women's legs as pins (never men's). I would like to know which type of pins are women legs being compared to?

- bobby pins
- bowling pins
- hairpins
- push pins
- rolling pins
- safety pins (unlikely but who knows!)
- sewing pins

**And when did it start coming into fashion?**

Comment: Personally I've never heard this, but then again I don't read a lot of fashion articles :) I'm taking a guess that it could have originated from any/all of the skinny, sharp, and pointy varieties of pins; the most obvious correlation I can think of is that it is an attempt to describe the legs as long and skinny, which is supposed to be attractive.

Comment: But the majority of the pins I listed are as you say, long, skinny *and* straight. Whatever happened to a pair of "shapely legs"?

Comment: Well, I'd definitely guess that it didn't originate from bowling pins or rolling pins ;) As for the rest, I don't know that we make much distinction between them in cases like this. "It was so quiet you could hear a pin drop." What kind of pin? I think it's equally plausible to imagine a bobby pin, a sewing pin, etc. Any small pin that's sharp and made of metal could pop to mind in that case. Haha, I don't know about "shapely" though. Like I said I've never heard *pin* like this, I'm just guessing! There are a lot of funny words evolving out there. One of the interesting things about language!

Comment: Mari-Lou, FWIW, I think your list is not complete because it lack of "pinup girl": "a girl or woman whose glamorous qualities make her a suitable subject for a pinup."

Comment: @Carlo_R. Definitely related to but not exactly the same. I think the expression originates form the US when the first Hollywood starlets (Betty Grable) would pose for posters that were destined to be "pinned" up onto a wall. Although I have left out one type of pin; I shan't tell, not yet!

Comment: Notice the top links if you search for `showing off her pins`? The Sun, The Express and Daily Mail... Does makes one think... And I ain't thinking USofA here

Comment: The Online Etymology Dictionary entry for [*pin*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pin&searchmode=none) states that the sense of a human leg came about in the 1520s (long before pinup girls). Also Macmillan Dictionary's entry for [pin](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pin#pin_15) says it is British informal and old-fashioned.

Comment: 1520s  well I never. Interesting.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou: Let that be a lesson to you! As with [bird = young woman](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116760/) that dates back to at least 1400, it's mostly a case of "nothing new under the sun".

Comment: @JLG: I wouldn't say it's *that* "old-fashioned". Practically all instances of [nice pair of pins](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22nice+pair+of+pins%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books are within the last decade or so.

Comment: OK, someone down-voted this. Why? WHY?

Comment: @Fumble: I'd guess that what drives the recency of that phrase is the seemingly modern "nice pair," not so much the word _pins_. Just a theory, though. P.S. (to Mari-Lou - Why the downvote?) - I'm guessing it was a woman who was jealous of those legs. ;^)

Comment: @J.R.: Very likely. I see nothing seriously old-fashioned about *nice [pair of] pins* (but then again, I'm pushing 60, so I may be biased). But I would certainly think it was a "facetious" usage if a DJ said *"C'mon! Let's have you up on your pins!"* for *"I want to see you all get up and dance"*.

Comment: But why are women's legs, especially young beautiful ones, defined as such? When it's been proven historically "pins" were used indiscriminately between both sexes and for all ages?

Comment: To be truthful, Mari-Lou, I don't think it's common slang, at least not here in the U.S. I can't recall ever hearing it prior to reading this question. As for why it's used where it's used (if it's used), I think it's just because some slang words seem more apt for certain contexts, such as when you're admiring someone's physique. It's not hard for me to imagine a young doctor admiring a woman at a bar, and saying to his friend, _"She's got nice pins!"_ but I have a much harder time imagining him in his clinic the next day, telling a patient, _"I think you have blood clots in your pins."_

Comment: @J.R ; Michael Plungjan and StoneyB both correctly pointed out that the term is primarily used by the British tabloid press; I'm glad to hear that "pins" hasn't crossed over the pond as I find it mildly offensive to women, albeit innocuous at the same time. It's just one of those things that I have discovered while perusing the web, and thought it curious.

Comment: the mondern Dutch for leg is "been" prononced "bane". The letter "b" is prononced very close to the english "p". There might be a connection from way back when the Flemish used to come over and buy wool from the East of England.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Pins* for *legs* is a very old slang use - *OED 1* earliest citation is from the play *Hyckescorner*, confidently dated 1497-1512:

> Than wolde I renne thyder on my pynnes As fast as I might goe.

At the time the phrase was coined none of the sorts of pin you list seem to have been in use under that name. The root sense of *pin* seems to have been *peg* (think of a *linchpin* or a *pin* joint), but by the 15th century it had already been extended to pointers, pinnacles, pedestals, spikes, wedges, brooches, and wire pins (like to today's sewing pins) used as fasteners. I suspect the original coinage was closer to “peg” — *stumps* in the same sense arises about the same time — but I find no evidence one way or another.

In any case, I doubt that people who use this colloquialism (who are not, in my experience, casual real-life speakers but pop-culture/celebrity journalists) have any particular kind of pin (or peg) in mind, or have any sense at all that some literal sense of *pin* lies behind the word. It's just faintly slangy, faintly retro, faintly humorous seasoning for otherwise drab and repetitive copy.

Comment: +1 for the quote in all its simplicity, "That I could run on my legs as fast as I might go" (correct?) has an air of tragic beauty.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am sorry to disillusion you, but the speaker is a hardened bawdmaster and debauchee who scorns sound religious counsel, declaring that if hell were full of such sluts as his "sweet trully-mully" Jane, Kate, Bess, and Sibley he would run there as fast his legs could carry him.

Answer (score 0):

Way back in the early sixties when I was a student nurse under 20 a male patient called out as I walked past him, “nice pair of pins”. I had never heard the expression before but realized it was a cat call and so I just smiled at him because he was sick and thought I had nice legs (even encased in a uniform going way below my legs (and measured every day by a teacher, sometimes using a ruler!)
I was a cyclist and ball player from way back so have muscular calves! I guess this male patient had quite bad eyesight! However, 2 husbands have liked my body so I guess my “pins are OK!